# This code causes an invalid syntax error. Why?

Tags: python

I was doing practice in code wars. And the following code gives me an invalid syntax error. I don't understand where the syntax gone wrong.

```
def is_divisible(n,x,y):
    
    a = n%x
    b = n%y
    
    if a == 0:
        if b == 0:
            print("true because " + str(n) + " is divisible by " +str(x) + " and " + str(y))
            
        else:
            print("false because " + str(n) + " is not divisible by " + str(y))
    elif a != 0:
        if b == 0:
            print("false because " + str(n) + " is not divisible by " +str(x))
        else:
            print("false because " + str(n) + " is neither divisible by "+str(x) " nor " +str(y))
```

And the error I get is this:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "tests.py", line 2, in 
> from solution import is_divisible
>
> File "/workspace/default/solution.py", line 16
> print("false because " + str(n) + " is neither divisible by "+str(x) " nor " +str(y))
> ^
> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Because you've forgot a `+`

Comment: between `str(x)` and `" nor"`, you forgot a  `+`

Comment: Its a simple typo, as mentioned. But, you shouldn't be doing it this way anyway! Consider [f-strings, or at least str.format](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/).

Comment: Ok. Thanks guys. I am totally new to coding, my mistake catching eye isn't sharp enough like you guys. I know its really fruastating to answer silly questions. But be patient I will do better next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a concatenation operator (`+`) in this line:
`print("false because " + str(n) + " is neither divisible by "+str(x) " nor " +str(y))`

Change that to:

`print("false because " + str(n) + " is neither divisible by "+str(x) + " nor " +str(y))`

As suggested by others, if you have Python version >= `3.6`, use the `f-string` alternative which is much more readable and less error-prone:

`print(f"false because {n} is neither divisible by {x} nor {y}")`

Comment: Using an f-string would be even better and much more readable: `print(f"false because {n} is neither divisible by {x} nor {y}")`

Comment: Edited to add the `f-string` approach but since the question is not tagged with `python-3`, I thought to keep the answer generic.

Comment: Python 3.6 is the [oldest supported version](https://endoflife.date/python). If they're using anything older, they absolutely should upgrade.